# MySql insert on duplicate key update - unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table definition:

```
create table mytable(
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  primary key (a, b),
  unique (b, c)
);

insert into mytable values (1,2,3);

select * from mytable;
    +---+---+------+
    | a | b | c    |
    +---+---+------+
    | 1 | 2 |    3 |
    +---+---+------+
```

The following statement has a surprising result:

```
mysql> insert into mytable (a, b, c) values (2, 2, 3) on duplicate key update a = 2, b = 2, c = 3;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from mytable;
+---+---+------+
| a | b | c    |
+---+---+------+
| 2 | 2 |    3 |
+---+---+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was expecting the insert/update to fail due to the unique constraint. I was most certainly not expecting to delete the record with primary key (1, 2) when I was dealing with primary key (2, 2).

Is this a bug???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is designed.  Your values were not deleted, but updated. This is from the MySQL documentation:

If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed. For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two statements have identical effect:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```